# Mathematica shuts down when calculating this limit

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, symbolic

**Bug introduced in 9.0.0 and fixed in 9.0.1**

---

I'm trying to compute this limit:

```
Limit[E^-(r^2)^(2*n)*r*2*Pi, n -> Infinity]
```

But, when I run the code above, *Mathematica* shuts down. I get a warning from Windows stating that the *Mathematica* 9 Kernel has stopped working. *Mathematica* itself gives no warning or message. Why is that?

Comment: Which version do you have? *Mathematica* 9 doesn't crash, although it also can't evaluate this limit. If it's a new crash, you should report this as a bug.

Comment: @OleksandrR. What I get is a warning from windows stating that the MAthematica 9 Kernel has stopped working... Mathematica gives no warning or message

Comment: Are you using 9.0.0? 9.0.1 doesn't seem to have this problem.

Comment: @OleksandrR. yes, 9.0.0

Comment: I've tagged it as a bug specific to version 9.0.0, because neither 8.0.4 nor 9.0.1 (the previous and next versions, respectively) have the same problem. I suggest updating *Mathematica*, if you can.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Ok

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With

```
 $Version
 (* 10.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (October 9, 2015) *)
```

Mathemeatica returns a limit that depends on `r`, as it should.

```
Plot[Limit[E^-(r^2)^(2*n)*r*2*Pi, n -> Infinity], {r, -2, 2}, AxesLabel -> {r, Lim}]
```

[image]

**Addendum**

Although `Limit` returns unevaluated for arbitrary `r`, it can be made to produce useful results by making assumptions on `r`.  For instance,

```
Piecewise[{Assuming[{#}, Limit[E^-(r^2)^(2*n)*r*2*Pi, n -> Infinity]], #} & /@ 
    {r < -1, r == -1, -1 < r < 1, r == 1, r > 1}]
(* Piecewise[{{0, r < -1}, {(-2*Pi)/E, r == -1}, {2*Pi*r, -1 < r < 1}, 
   {(2*Pi)/E, r == 1}}, 0] *)
```

which reproduces the plot above, apart from the discontinuities at `r = -1` and `r = 1`.

Comment: 9.0.1 can also plot this, although it can't evaluate the limit for arbitrary `r`.

Comment: @OleksandrR.  Sorry for my disjointed response a few hours ago.  My plane was about to take off.  Indeed, `Limit` also returns unevaluated for arbitrary `r` with Mathematica 10.3.  But, putting assumptions on it produces useful results, as I just added to my answer.